# get median of a columns based on the weights from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1     col2
 100      3
 200      2
 300      4
 400      1
```

Now I want to have median on col1 in such way col2 values will be the weights for each col1 values like this,

```
median of [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400] # 100 is 3 times as the weight is 3
```

I can do it by creating multiple rows based on weights but I can't allow more rows, is there any way to do it more efficiently without creating multiple rows either in python or pyspark

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the values then calculate median

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['col2']), 'col1'].median()
```

---

```
250.0
```